# Slider values doesn't update on observeEvent when nested in tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I am using a date slider that is dynamic on the selection of year from the UI. The slider options are nested in `tabPanel` but when the year is changed the date does not react.  I don't understand how to get the `observeEvent` to relay the new date.  The old date can be seen in the terminal from the discrepancy of `print(input$range)` vs `print(input$year)` when the year is changed to 2018. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.minicharts)


flow<-structure(list(site_no = c(11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 
                                 11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 11468500), 
                     WY = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
                            2018), flow = c(367, 411, 373, 392, 349, 245, 219, 198, 175, 
                                            154), Date = structure(c(17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 
                                                                     17638, 17639, 17640, 17641, 17642), class = "Date"), commonDate = structure(c(11064, 
                                                                                                                                                   11065, 11066, 11067, 11068, 11064, 11065, 11066, 11067, 11068
                                                                     ), class = "Date"), year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                  2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                              cols = list(site_no = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), WY = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), flow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector")), Date = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector")), commonDate = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

ant_data_clean<-structure(list(ANTENNA = c("DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", 
                                           "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", 
                                           "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "USTM", 
                                           "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", 
                                           "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", 
                                           "USTM", "USTM", "USTM"), Species = c("Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", 
                                                                                "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", 
                                                                                "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", 
                                                                                "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", 
                                                                                "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", 
                                                                                "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", 
                                                                                "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", 
                                                                                "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", 
                                                                                "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead"), date = structure(c(17273, 
                                                                                                                                           17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17638, 17639, 17640, 17641, 17642, 
                                                                                                                                           17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17638, 17639, 17640, 17641, 
                                                                                                                                           17642, 17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17638, 17639, 17640, 
                                                                                                                                           17641, 17642, 17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17638, 17639, 
                                                                                                                                           17640, 17641, 17642), class = "Date"), n = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        13, 15, 29, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 15, 19, 28, 58, 9, 20, 16, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        15, 14, 2, 3, 7, 4, 11, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 5, 4, 8, 14), lat = c(39.534772, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.534772, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417), lng = c(-123.748447, -123.748447, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.731349, -123.731349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349), year = c(2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


sppCols <- levels(factor(ant_data_clean$Species))

tilesURL <- "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"

basemap <- leaflet(width = "100%", height = "100%") %>%
  addTiles(tilesURL) 
parameter_tabs <- tabsetPanel(
  id = "slide",
  type = "hidden",
  tabPanel("2017",
           sliderInput("range", "Date range", as.Date("2017-04-17"), as.Date("2017-04-21"),
                       value = c(as.Date("2017-04-17")), step = 1,animate =animationOptions(interval = 250,loop=FALSE))
  ),
  tabPanel("2018", 
           sliderInput("range","Date range", as.Date("2018-04-17"), as.Date("2018-04-21"),
                       value = as.Date("2018-04-17"), step = 1,animate =animationOptions(interval = 250,loop=FALSE))
  )
)  


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "75%"),
  plotlyOutput("animate", width = "100%", height = "25%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                selectInput("year","Select year",choices = c(min(ant_data_clean$year):max(ant_data_clean$year)),selected = 2017),
                parameter_tabs,
                selectInput("spp", "Select species",choices = unique(sppCols), multiple = FALSE,selected = c("Coho Salmon")
                ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$year,{
    updateTabsetPanel(session=session,inputId = "slide", selected = input$year)
  })     
  
  
  filteredData <- reactive({
    print(input$range)
    print(input$year)
    ant_data_clean[ant_data_clean$date == input$range,]%>%
      drop_na(date) %>% 
      filter(Species %in% input$spp)
    
  })
  
  # Initialize map
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    basemap %>%
      addMinicharts(
        ant_data_clean$lng,ant_data_clean$lat,
        layerId = ant_data_clean$ANTENNA,
        width = 65, height = 150,
        transitionTime = 250
      )
  })
  
  # Update charts each time input value changes
  observe({
    TM <- filteredData()
    data <- TM %>% select(n) 
    
    #    }
    maxValue <- max(as.matrix(data))
    
    leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
      updateMinicharts(
        layerId = TM$ANTENNA,
        chartdata = data,
        maxValues = maxValue,
        type = "pie",
        showLabels = TRUE,
        transitionTime = 250
      )
  })  

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I think the conflicts is due to both inputs having the same id "range".
By giving them different id, it works for me.

I made the following changes :

1. give the sliderInputs different id, i.e "range1" and "range2" instead of "range".

In parameter_tabs

```
parameter_tabs <- tabsetPanel(
  id = "slide",
  type = "hidden",
  tabPanel("2017",
           sliderInput("range1", "Date range", as.Date("2017-04-17"), as.Date("2017-04-21"),
                       value = c(as.Date("2017-04-17")), step = 1,animate =animationOptions(interval = 250,loop=FALSE))
  ),
  tabPanel("2018", 
           sliderInput("range2","Date range", as.Date("2018-04-17"), as.Date("2018-04-21"),
                       value = as.Date("2018-04-17"), step = 1,animate =animationOptions(interval = 250,loop=FALSE))
  )
)
```

And 2. Update the code of reactive filtredData accordingly by using the sliderInput depending on which year (range1 for 2017 and range2 for 2018) was selected.

```
filteredData <- reactive({
    print("-------------------------")
    print(input$range1)
    print(input$range2)
    print(input$year)
    newrange <- case_when(
      input$year == 2017 ~ input$range1,
      input$year == 2018 ~ input$range2
    )
    print(newrange )
    ant_data_clean[ant_data_clean$date == newrange,]%>%
      drop_na(date) %>% 
      filter(Species %in% input$spp)
    
  })
```

Comment: You will have to define as a new reactive (outside the création of filtredData). Using réactiveValues also works, the code to do it is written in the answer of @timteafan

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option to solve the same problem.

1. Create `reactiveValues`
2. Update this `reactiveValues` with an `observeEvent` on `ìnput$year`. We can use `paste` and `gsub` so that we can add additional years without the need to touch the code here again.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.minicharts)


flow<-structure(list(site_no = c(11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 
                                 11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 11468500, 11468500), 
                     WY = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
                            2018), flow = c(367, 411, 373, 392, 349, 245, 219, 198, 175, 
                                            154), Date = structure(c(17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 
                                                                     17638, 17639, 17640, 17641, 17642), class = "Date"), commonDate = structure(c(11064, 
                                                                                                                                                   11065, 11066, 11067, 11068, 11064, 11065, 11066, 11067, 11068
                                                                     ), class = "Date"), year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                  2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                              cols = list(site_no = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), WY = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), flow = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector")), Date = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "collector")), commonDate = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

ant_data_clean<-structure(list(ANTENNA = c("DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", 
                                           "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", 
                                           "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "DSTM", "USTM", 
                                           "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", 
                                           "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", "USTM", 
                                           "USTM", "USTM", "USTM"), Species = c("Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", 
                                                                                "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", 
                                                                                "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", 
                                                                                "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", 
                                                                                "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", 
                                                                                "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", 
                                                                                "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Coho Salmon", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", 
                                                                                "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead", 
                                                                                "Steelhead", "Steelhead", "Steelhead"), date = structure(c(17273, 
                                                                                                                                           17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17638, 17639, 17640, 17641, 17642, 
                                                                                                                                           17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17638, 17639, 17640, 17641, 
                                                                                                                                           17642, 17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17638, 17639, 17640, 
                                                                                                                                           17641, 17642, 17273, 17274, 17275, 17276, 17277, 17638, 17639, 
                                                                                                                                           17640, 17641, 17642), class = "Date"), n = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        13, 15, 29, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 15, 19, 28, 58, 9, 20, 16, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        15, 14, 2, 3, 7, 4, 11, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 9, 5, 4, 8, 14), lat = c(39.534772, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 39.534772, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.534772, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        39.525417, 39.525417, 39.525417), lng = c(-123.748447, -123.748447, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.748447, -123.731349, -123.731349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -123.731349, -123.731349, -123.731349), year = c(2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


sppCols <- levels(factor(ant_data_clean$Species))

tilesURL <- "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Canvas/World_Light_Gray_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"

basemap <- leaflet(width = "100%", height = "100%") %>%
  addTiles(tilesURL) 
parameter_tabs <- tabsetPanel(
  id = "slide",
  type = "hidden",
  tabPanel("2017",
           sliderInput("range17", "Date range", as.Date("2017-04-17"), as.Date("2017-04-21"),
                       value = c(as.Date("2017-04-17")), step = 1,animate =animationOptions(interval = 250,loop=FALSE))
  ),
  tabPanel("2018", 
           sliderInput("range18","Date range", as.Date("2018-04-17"), as.Date("2018-04-21"),
                       value = as.Date("2018-04-17"), step = 1,animate =animationOptions(interval = 250,loop=FALSE))
  )
)  


    ui <- bootstrapPage(
      tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
      leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "75%"),
      plotlyOutput("animate", width = "100%", height = "25%"),
      absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                    selectInput("year","Select year",choices = c(min(ant_data_clean$year):max(ant_data_clean$year)),selected = 2017),
                    parameter_tabs,
                    selectInput("spp", "Select species",choices = unique(sppCols), multiple = FALSE,selected = c("Coho Salmon")
                    ))
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      observeEvent(input$year,{
        updateTabsetPanel(session=session,inputId = "slide", selected = input$year)
      })     
      
      date <- reactiveValues(range = NULL)
      
      observeEvent(input$year, {
        
        date$range <- input[[paste0("range", gsub("^20","", input$year))]]
      })
      
      filteredData <- reactive({
        print(date$range)
        print(input$year)
        ant_data_clean[ant_data_clean$date == date$range,]%>%
          drop_na(date) %>% 
          filter(Species %in% input$spp)
        
      })
      
      # Initialize map
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        basemap %>%
          addMinicharts(
            ant_data_clean$lng,ant_data_clean$lat,
            layerId = ant_data_clean$ANTENNA,
            width = 65, height = 150,
            transitionTime = 250
          )
      })
      
      # Update charts each time input value changes
      observe({
        TM <- filteredData()
        data <- TM %>% select(n) 
        
        #    }
        maxValue <- max(as.matrix(data))
        
        leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
          updateMinicharts(
            layerId = TM$ANTENNA,
            chartdata = data,
            maxValues = maxValue,
            type = "pie",
            showLabels = TRUE,
            transitionTime = 250
          )
      })  
      
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This does produce the correct values but the animate function on the slider does not work.